# High CPU usage troubleshoot

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, performance, troubleshooting

I don't know why but since this morning, my CPU is going crazy and when I checked the task manager I saw that my "system" process is variating between 50 and 100% on idle. I decided to analize a windows performance record with Windows Performance Analyzer, but when looking at the System process, nothing seemed weird. What looks weird to me is that the Idle process weights 98% and the System weights 0.32%...

Here is what I could get from WPA:
[image: WPA results]

And here are my computer specs:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Intel Core i7-6700K
- 32 GB RAM

Any advice on where I should look at to fix this ?

Comment: System is not doing anything special in your image except displaying the screen. The CPU might be Windows doing some maintenance or virus scan. For peace of mind, run deep antivirus checks, at least by Defender and Malwarebytes.

Comment: @harrymc I also thought about a malware and made scans with Bitdefender (my antivirus) and MBAM. Both scans returned negative. Would going for a PC reset insted of looking for the issue be easier ?

Comment: Reset would get rid of malware, but you will have to reinstall all your apps. I would take an image backup of the disk and have bootable media that can restore it, just in case. Before doing such drastic action, get as much information as you can. Perhaps from the Event Viewer, show us screenshots of System taking excessive CPU etc.